Feeling annoyed
I know this might sound superficial but I am really annoyed and I would like some advice. I am currently off work and I do have a history of high absentism. I am covered by the disability act.
I looked at my emails tonight and saw an email from another team leader ( not mine). The email describes a mistake I have made which I hold my hand up to, however, in the email she had suggested that the mistake might be due to my high absentism? I’m so annoyed I have worked in the job for 19 years and have an a good record. Is she allowed to do this or is is ok. She has made me feel so bad and question myself.

I have no idea what the email says. Perhaps the writer was trying to attribute the mistake to a more understandable / excusable cause and seem less like they were blaming you?


Is she allowed to do this

Of course she is allowed to send an email suggesting that the mistake you admit you made might be due to your high absenteeism.
That doesn't mean it was nice. That doesn't mean she was right.
But you can't stop someone from sending an email.

Fair or not, it is easy to blame someone that isn't there.
Can they do it? That isn't really a valid question. Should they do it? No really a meaningful question either.
What are your options about it? That is the question.
Accept it? Pushback?
Peel back the layers of this onion.

Determine what was the problem
What was your part in the problem
Did your overall attendence play a part in the problem

If you can do an honest analysis, then you'll have a clear view.
Either you'll have the points to pushback that the problem wasn't yours in the making. OR you can own the problem and work on a solution.
Possibly you'll see a different outcome. But the point is you'll be able to control the situation.
Keep in mind that no one "can make someone else feel" a given way.
Deconstruct the whole issue to your understanding. You're the one with the knowledge and understanding.
